# Unsupported docker v1 repository request. Error in Openshift

Tags: docker, jenkins, openshift, artifactory

Background:
I am running a Openshift build via Jenkins plugin in Openshift, which is then pushed to Artifactory. So image schema version 1 is deprecated for the push in Artifacrory. Intermittently, I guess some nodes are pushing the image schema version 1 in the build.
Container Runtime Version:  docker://1.13.1
oc v3.10.0+0c4577e-1
kubernetes v1.10.0+b81c8f8

Ask:
Would like to understand what causes these tags in the build ? is there a build agent controller that is responsible for tagging the image schema version? is there an article or doc, that I could read to understand this?  How to troubleshoot this error. As far as I am aware all the agent nodes use the same versions, I guess out of all nodes, the issue is with only one node. As when the same build goes to other nodes it gets completed with schema version 2. However, again the version of the agent nodes are similar, not sure where to start.

Error message:
Warning  Failed     1m (x3 over 2m)   kubelet,   Failed to pull image "products-docker-stage.artifactory.": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error: Status 400 trying to pull repository licence-module: "{\n  "errors" : [ {\n    "status" : 400,\n    "message" : "Unsupported docker v1 repository request for 'products-docker-stage'"\n  } ]\n}"
Warning  Failed     1m (x3 over 2m)   kubelet,   Error: ErrImagePull
Normal   BackOff    1m (x3 over 2m)   kubelet,   Back-off pulling image "products-docker-stage.artifactory.**"
Warning  BackOff    43s (x3 over 1m)  kubelet,   Back-off restarting failed container

## Error in Openshift

```
error: build error: Failed to push image: unauthorized: Pushing Docker images with manifest v2 schema 1 to this repository is blocked. For more information visit https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Advanced+Topics#AdvancedTopics-DockerManifestV2Schema1Deprecation
```

Comment: Is it possible that your build nodes has local Docker caches? if so, you might have a local image with schema version 1 in one of those caches

Comment: I don't think so, as the build is happening via Jenkins pipeline. But just to confirm what are the places you want me to look, please. I could give an output to the places you require. 

Also, I believe the issue with some access issue to the Artifactory from Jenkins or Openshift, not sure where to dig. But these are what I have updated and changed to see if it works.

Changed:- sudo  cat /etc/sysconfig/docker
OPTIONS=' --selinux-enabled       --signature-verification=False --insecure-registry myartifactiryurl.com'
Added
/etc/docker/daemon.json 
{
  "disable-legacy-registry": true

Comment: Error
======
error: build error: Failed to push image: unauthorized: Pushing Docker images with manifest v2 schema 1 to this repository is blocked. For more information visit https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Advanced+Topics#AdvancedTopics-DockerManifestV2Schema1Deprecation